# Comparing two tables and finding partial match (SQL / Oracle)

Tags: sql, join, wildcard, mismatch

I haven't quite found an answer to this problem, it seems a bit tricky (and yes, I am a beginner). I have two tables; `eb_site` and `eb_register` and they both have the column `id_glo` which connects them. The values within these fields are not quite the same though, the number is the connecting factor. An example:

`eb_site = kplus.hs.dlsn.3074823`

`eb_register = kplus.hs.register.3074823-1"`

How could I select the ones ie make a list where the number in eb_register deviates from the number in `eb_site` (and disregard  the mismatch between dlsn/register).

And also where the `eb_register` has a -1 at the end as in the example (the fixed ones don't have the -1 at the end).

Thanks for any replies.

edit: oops sorry guys, worded it badly, have edited

Rgds,

Steinar

Comment: This needs a serious re-design.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  there is lots of room to make this question better.

Comment: thanks, looked at it before, will re-read it

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this site is amazing! Have no access to the database at the moment, will take a look tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the quality of the solution will depend on the possible `id_glo` values and the sql dialect you can use.
as a start, try

```
    select s.id_glo
         , r.id_glo
      from eb_site     s
inner join eb_register r on (     replace(replace(s.id_glo, 'kplus.hs.register.', ''), 'kplus.hs.dlsn.', '') <> replace(replace(r.id_glo, 'kplus.hs.register.', ''), 'kplus.hs.dlsn.', '')
                              and replace(replace(r.id_glo, 'kplus.hs.register.', ''), 'kplus.hs.dlsn.', '') not like replace(replace(s.id_glo, 'kplus.hs.register.', ''), 'kplus.hs.dlsn.', '') || '-%'
           )
         ;
```

this query assumes that:

- there are no more different prefixes as the ones you've given
- number complements will only occur in records from `eb_register`

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers match, then the reverse of the numbers match.  The following extracts the number (and final decimal point) from each key, using SQL Server syntax:

```
select *
from eb_site s join
     eb_register r
     on left(REVERSE(s.id_glo), charindex('.', reverse(s.id_glo))) =
        left(REVERSE(r.id_glo), charindex('.', reverse(r.id_glo)))
```

In other databases the `charindex()` might need to be replaced by another function, such as `instr()`, `location()`, or `position()`.

Comment: the join condition matches records with identical numbers while it should do so when numbers differ ( do _not_ replace `=` with `<>` as this would mark records different that only differ in their `-` adjoined parts ).